# Matlab Bessel function and interpolation

Tags: matlab, interpolation

I am trying to finish an assignment and I don't really know how to do what the question asks. I am not looking for a complete answer, but just an understanding on what I need to use/do to solve the question. Here is the question:

> We are asked to provide an interpolant for the Bessel function of the first
> kind of order zero, J0(x).
>
> (a) Create a table of data points listed to 7 decimal places for the interpolation points
> x1 = 1.0, x2 = 1.3, x3 = 1.6, x4 = 1.9, x5 = 2.2.
> [Hint: See Matlab's help on BesselJ.]
>
> (b) Fit a second-degree polynomial through the points x1, x2, x3. Use this interpolant
> to estimate J0(1.5). Compute the error.

What exactly does BesselJ do? And how do I fit a second degree polynomial through the three points?

Thanks,

Mikeshiny

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the zeroth order Bessel function of the first kind:

http://mathworld.wolfram.com/BesselFunctionoftheFirstKind.html

Bessel functions are to differential equations in cylindrical coordinates as sines and cosines are to ODEs in rectangular coordinates.

Both have series representations; both have polynomial approximations.

Here's a general second-order polynomial:

```
y = a0 + a1*x + a2*x^2
```

Substitute in three points `(x1, y1)`, `(x2, y2)`, and `(x3, y3)` and you'll have three equations for three unknown coefficients `a0`, `a1`, and `a2`.  Solve for those coefficients.

Take a look at the plot of `y = J0(x)` in the link I gave you.  You want to fit a 2nd order poly through some range.  So - pick one.  The first point is (0, 1).  Pick two more - maybe x = 1 and x = 2.  Look up the values for y at those values of x from a J0 table and evaluate your coefficients.

Here are my three points: (0,1), (1, 0.7652), (2.4048, 0).

When I calculate the coefficients, here's the 2nd order polynomial I get:

```
J0(x) = 1 -0.105931124*x -0.128868876*x*x
```

Comment: But what do I use for y1, y2, and y3?

Comment: The values of the function you're trying to interpolate at x1, x2, and x3 of course.

Comment: is that the first three values I get from besselj?

Comment: "First three"?  It's a continuous function.

Comment: Thanks for the help, I figured it out